# My Android layout design is not on the same placement when running it on emulator, and shows them incorrect positioned

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android 2.3.3 version and making a tic tac toe game on it. I am  having a problem with a placement of objects when designing the layout, and  also there is something wrong with a game state of the game. 
Any help would be great !

look below  image of my layout 
[image]

Here is my xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sherzod.ion.tictactoeandroid.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:background="@drawable/board"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView9"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="3"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView10"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="4"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="5" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="6"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="7"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:onClick="dropIn"
            android:tag="8"/>

    </GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my Main Activity file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // 0 = yellow ; 1 = red;
    int activePlayer = 0;

    // ** 2 means unplayed
    int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};


    public void dropIn(View view) {

        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

        System.out.println(counter.getTag().toString());

        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());


        if(gameState[tappedCounter] == 2) {
            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;
        }

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

        if(activePlayer == 0) {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
            activePlayer = 1;

        }else {
            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
            activePlayer = 0;
        }



        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360).setDuration(200);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to your layout:

- Added `columnWeight` and `rowWeight` to each grid item
- Added `layout_gravity` `fill` to each grid item

Check the below `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/board" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="4"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="6" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="7" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="8" />

</GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: sorry, but when  i run it on emulator it is all messed up !

Comment: I checked on emulator too, but I did it without the `GridLayout` background. Can you check without the `GridLayout` background?

Comment: Do you know why drag and drop feature not position items as expected, or should i make any configuration to make layout design view to look the same when running it on emulator ?